# php namespace load javascript file error

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to load a javascript and css file with link and script tags. The project uses php namespaces so the files are trying to load via the router script that sets the controllers. Maybe a little more explanation is needed.

When the visitor first comes to `http://site0` the root `.htaccess` file rewrites to the `/public` directory with the `/public/.htaccess` file rewrites everything to the `/public/index.php` file. The `/public/index.php` is just a `spl_autoload` function and calls the `router.class.php` script that decides which controller class to call.

Contents of `root .htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.css$
RewriteRule (styles/[^/]+\.css)$ /$1 [L]

# File is located in /foldername/images/
# Internal redirect. Does not change address in the browsers address bar.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpg|png)$
RewriteRule ^.*(images)/(.*)(\.gif|jpg|png)$ $1/$2$3 [L]

# File is located in /foldername/scripts/.
# Internal redirect. Does not change address in the browsers address bar.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.js$
RewriteRule (scripts/[^/]+\.js)$ /$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^$ public/  [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

Contents of `public/.htaccess` :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1     [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

Contents of `public/index.php` :

```
 <?
 //set_include_path('PATH_TO_GLOBAL_LIBS; PATH_TO_LIBRARY_1; PATH_TO_LIBRARY_X; PATH_TO_DOCUMENT_ROOT');

define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define ('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

include_once (ROOT . DS . 'inc/dbconf.php');

function multi_autoloader($class)
{
    $class = preg_replace('/^((\w*)\\\){2}/', '', $class);

    $file = ROOT . DS . str_replace('\\', DS, strtolower($class)) . '.class.php';

        if ( file_exists($file) )
        {
           require ($file);        
        }
}

spl_autoload_register('multi_autoloader');  

use potts\john\libs\router\Router as Router;

$router = Router::getInstance();
$router->initRouter();
```

The `router.class.php` file is quite large but if you need to see it, let me know. Via `console/inspector` I get a status `500` from both css and javascript files. In a project where I didn't need to use php namspaces all worked fine. So this has to be a problem caused by the namspaces.

Any suggestions on how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's an ugly hack but it works :

```
/**
 * Sets the appropriate controller
 * 
 * 
 * @return object $this->controller
 */ 

private function setController() 
{

   $this->_seo_uri = $this->seoUrl();

   $this->__controller = array_shift($this->_seo_uri);

        if ($this->__controller == 'styles')
        {
               /* dev purposes only. php will return error that gets 
                  appended to end of file.
                */
          ini_set('display_errors',0);

          /* include will return file with mime type 'text/html 
             thus not interpreting file as stylesheet
           */
           header('Content-type: text/css');  

           // readfile works too. your choice...   
           //readfile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/styles/style.css');

             include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/styles/style.css'); 


        }
        elseif ($this->__controller == 'scripts')
        {
               /* dev purposes only. php will return error that gets 
                  appended to end of file.
               */
          ini_set('display_errors',0); 

             include ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/scripts/gui.js');


        }
        else 
        {

            $this->_controller = ucfirst($this->__controller);

            $this->_controller = $this->_controller . "_Controller";


            $this->_base_namespace = '\bizdir\bizvend\controllers\\' . $this->__controller . '\\' . strtolower($this->_controller);

              //use $this->_base_namespace as $this->_controller;

           $this->controller = new $this->_base_namespace;

            return $this->controller;


        }


}
```

Refer to where I'm testing $this->__controller for either styles or scripts. What was happening is in the link and script tags the directory (either /styles/ or /scripts/) was being set as the controller in the namespace and the router class was trying to find the Styles_Controller class or the Scripts_Controller class. I'm probable going to have to test for images as well when I get to that point.

Hope this saves someone else a few hours of headbanging.

Any cleaner ways... I'm open to suggestions.